# Equality of Borel measures

Tags: integration, measure-theory, borel-sets

Suppose that $f\in C_c(\mathbb{R}^N)$ is an arbitrary compactly supported continuous function, such that the integral equality
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^N\times\mathbb{R}^M}f(x)d\mu(x,y)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}f(x)d\nu(x)$$
holds. Here $\mu$ and $\nu$ are Borel measures on their respective spaces. Is it necessarily true that $\nu(B)=\mu(B\times\mathbb{R}^M)$ for all Borel sets $B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^N)$? It looks like it is true, by the mollification argument of characteristic function, but I am not fully convinced.

Comment: Take arbitrary $\mu$ and $\nu$ and $f\equiv 0$. Then all your assumptions are fulfilled but still $\nu(B)=\mu(B\times\mathbb{R}^M)$ doesn't hold necessarily…

Comment: Lets say $f$ is assumed to be not identically zero.

Comment: Then still your question is not really well defined… for the first integral $f$ has to be a mapping from $\Bbb R^N \times \Bbb R^M$… for the second a mapping from $\Bbb R^N$… $f$ cannot fit  both.